# Why can't I access browser cookies when sent through POST request to express js

Tags: reactjs, express

I am sending this axios "POST" request from reactjs.

```
 Axios.post(`http://localhost:3003/test`, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

and I get null when i try to access req.headers.cookie or req.cookies from express

```
app.post("/test",(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.headers.cookie);
  console.log(req.cookies);
  res.send(req.headers.cookie);
})
```

but when i change the above request to get, the cookie is accessible. But I need to send through POST only.